# SQL Server setvar

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to get some values into a stored procedure and put them into variables with setvar. So I get my values with stored procedure's parameters but I can figure out how to put them into script variables. Here is my code :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_check_and_drop]
    @serverName varchar(50),
    @bddName varchar(50),
    @objectToCheck varchar(50),
    @objectName varchar(250)
AS
BEGIN
    print(@serverName)
    print(@bddName)

    **:setvar srv_RUNGIS [@serverName]
    :setvar db_RUNGIS [@bddName]**

    DECLARE @query varchar(max)

    SET @query = 'IF OBJECT_ID(N''' + @objectName + ''', ''P'') IS NOT NULL
              BEGIN
                  DROP ' + @objectToCheck + ' ' +  @objectName + ' ;
                  print( ' + @objectName + ' ' + @objectToCheck + ' $(srv_RUNGIS)' + ')
              END
              print( ''pas d''action $(srv_RUNGIS)'')'


    EXEC (@query) at $(srv_RUNGIS)
END
GO
```

Thanks for helping me to figure this out

Comment: `:setvar` is an sqlcmd (client) command. By the time the SP is running, its entirely within the server and `:setvar` is meaningless to SQL Server itself.

Comment: So I can't use it with a stored procedure?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: thx for the tip :)

Comment: I am scared that you have a procedure that will drop any object. This has poor design written all over it. And it is extremely vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: This is just a tool to help with sql patches for an application we are migrating

Comment: You may be better served with something external of SQL Server, like a PowerShell script.  It would be much easier to make the connections.